# Item Selector Custom URL eXtension issue with Tridion core service

Tags: 2011, core-service

I followed the following tutorial : http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx to create a tree based on the one on administration panel with the structure groups, sites, pages, components, etc.

I can create the root with the websites but when I try to access to **Building Blocks**, **Sites** or **Categories and Keywords** I find an error, here is the code related:

```
case ItemType.StructureGroup:
    using (var client = new TridionClient())
    {
        var items = client.Client.GetList(uri.ToString(),new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData(){Recursive = false});    
        toReturn.AddRange(ConvertToListTreeNode(items));
    }
    break;
```

and the exception:

> *System.ServiceModel.FaultException'1
>   {"Unexpected list type: Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData."}*

Server stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService.GetList(String id, SubjectRelatedListFilterData filter)
   at AdminPanel.TreeHelper.PopulateNode(String uri) in \\*\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AdminPanel\AdminPanel\TreeHelper.cs:line 241
   at AdminPanel.Controllers.HomeController.Node(String url) in \\*\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AdminPanel\AdminPanel\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 21
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

Any suggestion is welcome,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of SDL Tridion are you using?

Comment: SDL Tridion 2011

Comment: I think it might help if you add a little bit more of the code to your question, also, when you debug it, what is the actual value of the URI you are calling `GetList` with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally resolved it, with the tutorial, we cannot use **GetList()** methods (with your client), it is mandatory to parse it in xml and then read it.